# X axes labels always get cut off for matplotlib subplots on a web page

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plotted matplotlib subplots generated from a pandas dataframe on a web page using Flask. Here's the relevant code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from io import BytesIO,StringIO
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.rcParams['xtick.color']='k'
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize']='x-large'
travel_df_new.unstack(level=0).plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, legend=False)
buff = BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buff, format='png', dpi=100)
buff.seek(0)
```

The x axes labels always tend to get cut off , even if I set **plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize']='x-small'**.

Also, haven't found a way to rotate **xtick labels inside rcParams**.

My image is not covering the entire web page, so not sure if I need rotation.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `plt.tight_layout()` just before saving the figure? Maybe this will fix the problem of the cropped labels.

Comment: That sure worked. But that reduces the y axis scale for the uppermost graph. Any way to keep the same scales?

Comment: Did it change only for the uppermost graph? Could you post an updated image?

Comment: It did fix the cropped labels but for the upper most graph Y axes scale changed from 0-400 to 0-250. The average_spending,CA graph

Comment: You could set the limits for the uppermost graph manually with `ylim(0,400)`. Maybe this will work.

Comment: where exactly do i add that part?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot answer that. I'm not familiar with how this line works: `travel_df_new.unstack(level=0).plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, legend=False)`

Comment: hey..if you could put your suggrestions of ylim and plt.tight.layout() as answers , I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `plt.tight_layout()` to fix the cropped x labels. Normally, you can set the y limits of a plot with `ylim(0, 400)`. If you have subplots instead of a plot, which I assume is the case here, maybe `set_ylim(0,400)`. Maybe you will find some further help here: [How to set axes limits in each subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261054/how-to-set-axes-limits-in-each-subplot)